# I am having serious problems customizing my views template to displayblog entries in drupal 7

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am having serious problems customizing my views template to displayblog entries in drupal 7.

please anyone with knowledge of what can help me please reply. i have gone through a couple of drupal documentations but no luck. my field.tpl.php seem to be the only template that actually affect my displays even though i have views-view-field.tpl.php, views-view--blog.tpl.php in the template .

Answer (score 1):

In the view settings, under format, show, make sure you have fields selected, not content.
Under advanced, theme, click information to see which template files are being used, and click rescan if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created or edited a view, please check under **FORMAT** section this should be **Show:Fields** and under **Advanced** section look for **Theme:Information** and click onto this, there will be a popup with all possible templates for the display plugin and for the style plugins. All field tpl will be available here those are exists in views fields, you can find your own and use as per your requirement.

Comment: LOL, isn't that almost exactly the same as the answer I posted?

Answer (score -1):

When you edit your view open "Advanced" section on the right (collapsed by default) and click on "Information" from "Theme: Information" (last option in that section). There you can see what templates are used (bolded ones) and what could be used instead. You can even click on template description at the beginning of the line, and code will be displayed. Grab that code (copy) and create new template file with one of offered names. Place that template file in your theme and clear the cache. Now you can modify template by your needs.

Also, you even don't have to use all that hierarchy (even that's desirable), but you can i.e. find the template file that are looping over the rows and inside that loop put your html, so lower rank templates won't be included (i.e. template that iterates over fields or even over rows) . Again not so clear solution, but it works for me. I prefer having less template files and I know that nobody will work on that theme except me.